# How to find acrued billing charges for Windows Azure

Tags: windows, azure, billing

Is there a way or place to go to find out how much usage and ultimately costs have accrued against your Windows Azure account ? I am really interested in usage details so that I can get an estimate of costs for our application in test and try to predict when I scale it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a complete picture of metering / billing info programatically. However, your Windows Azure account has detailed monthly billing statements that break everything down: compute time per role, bandwidth, storage consumption, etc.

Here's the link on the portal, at [windows.azure.com](http://windows.azure.com):
[image]

Then, sign in:
[image]

Finally: view your bills:
[image]

EDIT: If you need a tool to generate load on your system, for metering/billing purposes, you can easily do so with something like [LoadStorm](http://www.loadstorm.com), as it's Testing-as-a-Service with nothing to install. Alternatively, you can use Visual Studio's test agents, but then you'll be throttled by local resources (load generation machines and bandwidth).

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I couldn't see the forest for all the trees in the way on this one. though, I searched numerous websites with bing and google to get any mention of how to view the invoices and got no where. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to David's answer, there are some tools starting to come through to assist with this problem  - e.g. see http://www.questcloudtools.com/azure/subscription-manager/

[image: Quest tools]

Disclaimer: I've not actually installed or used this myself

Comment: The link appears to be invalid and I can't find this application on the site I'm redirected to.

Comment: This was the original press report - http://www.quest.com/news-release/quest-software-unveils-tools-for-microsoft-azure-infrastructure-and-a-052011-814180.aspx - but maybe quest have reorganized products now that azure has changed, and now that Quest has been sold. There are better tools available now from Microsoft