# By Azure Scaling how much bill charged

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

How can we find out how much money we are saving by scaling (via increasing and decreasing instance) our Windows Azure application?

Also, is there a way to find out how much database storage is used and its cost, and how much bandwidth is used and its cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is currently any way to measure in an immediate way how your Windows Azure application changes affect your billing and usage.  There is, however, a [feature request](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/1143971-billing-usage-api) for a billing/usage API you could vote on.

SQL Azure includes two system views that can detail your storage and bandwidth usage.

> The [`sys.database_usage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951626.aspx) view lists the number, type, and duration of
>   databases on the server and the [`sys.bandwidth_usage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951628.aspx) view describes the
>   bandwidth used with each database.

The above was excerpted from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621788.aspx) article.

### Additional Links

In particular - [How to find acrued billing charges for Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206810/how-to-find-acrued-billing-charges-for-windows-azure)
In general - Search Stack Overflow for ["Azure Billing"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bazure%20%2bbilling)